# Cloudwatch Log Groups "AND OR" search

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I would like to use the cloudwatch loggroup filter to find errors for 2 request IDs.

I know how to do an OR: `?"request_id_1" ?"request_id_2"`

I know how to AND: `"ERROR" "request_id_2"`

How do I write a query to find all ERROR messages for either request_id_1 OR request_id_2?

PS: I know how to do this in log insights, but I want to be able to do this [filter queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html). Is it possible?